# How do I prevent jQuery events from bubbling up to parent elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of nested UL's that are like this:

```
<ul class="categorySelect" id="">
  <li class="selected">Root<span class='catID'>1</span>
    <ul class="" id="">
      <li>First Cat<span class='catID'>2</span>
        <ul class="" id="">
          <li>cat in First<span class='catID'>3</span>
            <ul class="" id="">
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>another cat in first<span class='catID'>4</span>
            <ul class="" id="">
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>cat in root<span class='catID'>5</span>
        <ul class="" id="">
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I then have jQuery that I intended to move the `"selected"` class to different LIs on `click()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("ul.categorySelect li").click(function () {
        $("ul.categorySelect li.selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    })

});
```

When I tested this, at first it didn't appear to be working at all. I added an `alert("click")` inside the click event function and I was able to tell that it was working, but the click event registered on both the child LI and parent LIs which meant that ultimately the root LI would always end up as selected.

Is there a way to prevent the `click()` event from executing on parent LIs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/); the link provides an example.

Comment: thanks. I knew it was something easy... just wasn't sure what to look for.